# point on line to form angle

Tags: trigonometry

In planning some video game camera behavior, I hit a math problem I am having some difficulty with. The camera in this case is restricted to moving along a line and chooses a location along the line to get close to important objects while keeping them in frame.

So to phrase the question in a mathy way: 
Given a line (through points $L_1$ and $L_2$ in the drawing), two points $A$ and $B$ not on the line, and an angle $\theta$ (based on the camera's field-of-view), how would you calculate the possible locations of a point $P$ on that line such that $\measuredangle APB = \theta$?

(It looks like there could be zero, one, or two solutions depending on $\theta$ and where the points are in relation to the line)

[example drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq0C7.png)

Comment: Do you want exactly $\theta$ or $\le\theta$?

Comment: Exactly $\theta$. The idea is that if the current position makes $\angle APB > \theta$, move the camera as little as needed to fit them in frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a line segment $\overline{AB}$, the locus of points $P$ such that $\angle{APB}$ is constant is a pair of circular arcs that pass through $A$ and $B$.

[image: constant-angle arcs]

The centers of these arcs lie on the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AB}$ at a distance of $\frac12|AB\cot\theta|$ from the line segment. This value comes from the fact that $\angle{ACB}$ is $2\theta$.

Once you have the two circles, it’s a straightforward computation to find their intersections with the camera rail. You’ll need to take a bit of care to reject solutions that are outside of these arcs: when $\theta$ is acute, you only want points on the circle that are on the same side of $\overline{AB}$ as the circle’s center—the solid arcs in the above illustration; when it’s obtuse, you want the arc on the opposite side—the broken arcs in the illustration. If $\theta=\pi/2$, then there’s effectively only one circle and its center is the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$. There can be as many as four solutions, two for each arc.

Comment: You might also want to know where to point the camera: the angle bisector intersects the line through the two centers (the perpendicular bisector of $A$ and $B$) where the latter meets the opposite arc of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we can first assume that $A$ and $B$ lie on the same vertical line (say $x=1$). If they don't, consider the intersection between lines $(PA),(PB)$ and $x=1$ which gives $A'$ and $B'$.

You can divide angle $\theta$ in two components $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.

$C$ has same $y$ coordinate than $P$ and you have
$$\tan(\theta_1)= y_A-y_P$$
$$\tan(\theta_2)= y_P-y_B$$

Then $\theta = \theta_1+\theta_2 = \arctan(y_A-y_P)+\arctan(y_P-y_B) = \arctan\left(\frac{y_A-y_B}{1-(y_A-y_P)(y_P-y_B)}\right)$

Be careful with $\arctan$ identities and make sure required conditions to apply them are verified. Then you should be able to solve

$$(y_A-y_P)(y_B-y_P) = \frac{y_A-y_B}{\tan(\theta)}-1$$

which is a polynomial of second order in $y_P$ (there are at least numerical solutions when discriminant is positive). You can extend this calculations for general $x$ coordinates of $A$ and $B$ (being careful with $\arctan$)

Here is an illustration

[image: Illustration]