# Calculating the location of a robot geometrically

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

My team is looking to provide a piece of code that locates a robot on an X/Y grid with ~cm precision. The robot is equipped with a camera/servo combination which is used to uniquely identify columns with known positions which sit outside of the board that the robot can move on.

The robot (R) can determine the angles between itself and any post (A, B, C, etc) via computer vision and measurement of the servo value that rotates the camera. It cannot determine the distance from itself to any post, but it knows the location (and therefore distances, angles) between any posts. This is a priori knowledge of the board that is programmed into the robot.

For a single triangle formed by ABR, it does not seem to be intuitively possible to locate a robot, because only one angle (R), and one distance (AB) is known. Thinking that we could solve the problem by including more points, we tried including BCR. This seems to intuitively provide enough points to definitely locate a robot, but the math we have done does not point to a single answer. This could be due to real-world assumptions that we have not been able to put in an equation form. For example, the robot never leaves the board, therefore no solutions outside of that box on the grid are valid.

- How can I calculate the position of robot R, given locations A, B, C, etc?
- What is the minimum number of columns needed to locate the robot?
- Do the "real-world" assumptions mentioned above, need to be taken into account in order to successfully locate the robot?

[image: Robot Grid]

Comment: Do you have the individual bearings to each post or only the angles between posts?

Comment: If it’s the latter, then the problem comes down to finding the intersection of two circles. I believe that, with suitable placement, three posts should suffice. I can write something up tomorrow, but in the meantime, see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2188315/265466) for the underlying idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As caveat says, if you have a general position, then you need 4 columns. In the case that is shown in the picture, however, where the straight lines through A and B and through B and C do not cross the admissible area for the robot, three columns are enough.

The reason is that in this case, B and C will always be seen 'from the same side'. This means that you know the angle you measure between the robot and the lines to B and C will always be such that you know it's orientation. In the picture, the angle CRB will always be positive, because the ray RC is 'to the right of' the ray RB.

If this is known, then the geometrical place which describes all the possible positions of the robot under which the points B and C are visible under the specific oriented angle you measured ($\alpha$) is part of a circle (shown green below). That circle goes through B and C, see the picture.

[image: geometrical locus of points which see a pair of points under a given angle]

It is only part of the circle, because in the remaining part you would see B and C under the angle of $180°-\alpha$ instead. If we didn't know about the orientation of the angle, then we would have to add the image of the green circle part when mirrored on line BC to our list of possible positions of the robot.

The same can of course be done with the angle you measured from R to A and B or from R to A and C. If you have 2 such circle parts and know their equations, you can calculate their points of intersection. Let's say you choose B,C and A,B. Because both circles go through B (which is impossible for the robot to be in), the only other possible point for the robot to be is the other point of intersection!

Now we need to determine the equation for the each circle. I'll do the math for B,C here. A circle's general equation is

$$(x-x_M)^2 + (y-y_M^2) = r^2,$$

where $(x_M,y_M)$ are the coordinates of the midpoint and $r$ is the radius of the circle.

Let's start with the mid point M. Since the circle will always go through B and C, M will be located on the perpendicular bisector m of BC. You can calculate the midpoint X of B and C beforehand and also a unit vector ($u_m$) of the direction of m. Choose it in such a way that the unit vector points from X to the side in which the robot is. So we have now

$$x_M = x_X + t\cdot {u_m}_x, y_M = y_X + t\cdot {u_m}_y$$,

where $t$ is the (as of now) unknown length of XM.

If you remember some lessons about angles in a circle, you'll see that angle CMB is equal to $2\alpha$ and that angle CMX is again equal to $\alpha$. Finally, angle MCX is equal to $90°-\alpha$.

Since the length of CX is known (half the length of BC) we now get

$$t={\rm length}(XM) =\tan(90°-\alpha)\cdot {\rm length}(CX) = \cot(\alpha)\cdot {\rm length}(CX)$$

If we put this into the above formula, we get finally values for the coordinates of our midpoint M!

I'll skip now on explaining why this formula stays correct even when we have an $\alpha > 90°$, where my above picture is no longer correct because then the midpoint M wanders to the other side of the line BC. But in this case our $\cot(\alpha)$ becomes negative and our calculated M also wanders to the other side of line BC.

So we now have the coordinates of our Midpoint M, we now only need the radius to get the complete equation. But the radius is the just the distance from any point on the circle to the midpoint, so just calculate the distance from M to B,C or R and you are good to go.

So where are we now? I have shown how to obtain the equation for the circle that contains the geometrical locus of all points under which 2 given points are to be seen under a given oriented angle.

Get 2 of those equations and determine the common points:

$$ (x-x_{M1})^2 + (y-y_{M1})^2  = r_1^2$$
$$ (x-x_{M2})^2 + (y-y_{M2})^2  = r_2^2$$

Take the difference of those 2 equations. All the quadratic terms in the unknown $x$ and $y$ will vanish, you are left with a linear equation. Transform that linear equation into the form $y=ax+b$ and plug it into on of the above equations for the circles. You will get a quadratic equation. One solution of it will be the common point that you choose for the angles (e.g, if you choose to use the angles between B,C and A,B, then B will be the common point). The other is the position of the robot

---

Now the above (as complicated as it is) is only the purely geometrical side of things. In reality, you will be confronted with

a) malfunctioning sensors that will, from time to time, produce just incorrect data, and
b) a limited accuracy of measurements.

Because of b) it is therefore much better not to just use the 3 columns that I said are necessary, but to use as many as possible/feasible. On top of these calculations you may need to do some calculation estimating how accurate your position is, taking into account the inaccuracy of the measurements.

For a), you may need to keep track of your calculated position and discard it if would show that you move 10cm in 1s when you can only move at have that speed, or somthing similar.

Comment: You beat me to it. I would suggest another practical consideration, which is to set the posts back away from the edge of the field. As you near the line joining a pair of posts, the radius of the circle gets very large, which can result in floating-point resolution artifacts. Another benefit of having the lines through pairs of posts not intersect the field is that you don’t have to deal with the special case of $\theta=n\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

You only need two posts with known positions to determine the robot's position as long as the two posts and the robot are not collinear. But you can always prevent this from happening by placing the posts in such a way that the line connecting them doesn't intersect the robot's grid.

Once you have a pair of posts that aren't collinear with the robot's position, pick an origin and an $x$-axis and $y$-axis. Suppose you have post $A$ at $(x_A,y_A)$ and post $B$ at $(x_B,y_B)$ and let $\theta_A$ be the angle that the robot $R$ makes with post $A$ and $\theta_B$ be the angle that the robot $R$ makes with post $B$, each measured from the positive $x$ direction.

Then the slope of the line that passes through the robot and post $A$ is $m_{AR}=\tan(\theta_A)$ and the slope of the line that passes through the robot and post $B$ is $m_{BR}=\tan(\theta_B)$.

So we can find the equation of the line that passes through the robot and post $A$ using the point-slope formula as
$$
y=m_{AR}(x-x_A)+y_A
$$
and the equation of the line that passes through the robot and post $B$ as
$$
y=m_{BR}(x-x_B)+y_B.
$$

We wish to find the simultaneous solution to this system of equations, so we have
$$
m_{AR}(x-x_A)+y_A=m_{BR}(x-x_B)+y_B
$$
so that the $x$-coordinate of the robot's position is
$$
x=\frac{y_B-y_A+m_{AR}x_A-m_{BR}x_B}{m_{AR}-m_{BR}}.
$$
Then, substituting our $x$-coordinate back into the first equation, we find the $y$-coordinate of the robot's position is
$$
y=m_{AR}\left(\frac{y_B-y_A+m_{AR}x_A-m_{BR}x_B}{m_{AR}-m_{BR}}-x_A\right)+y_A.
$$

Comment: What if either or both of the angles is $\pm\pi/2$? $\theta_A=\theta_B+\pi$ Is a potential problem, too, but a good choice of posts avoids that.

Comment: I suspect that they don’t have absolute bearings to the posts, but only the angles between posts. If it’s the former, then of course the problem is a straightforward one of finding the intersection of two lines as you’ve described.

Comment: @amd: Your first comment brings to light the general problems of when the two posts and the robot are collinear or when one of the lines has an undefined slope. For the former, a third post fixes that problem and for the latter, we can code that special case away. For your second comment, we will have to wait and see if the OP can clarify things.

Comment: You can deal with ”undefined slope” by not using the slope/intercept form of the equation of a line. Use the normal equation instead and no special handling of vertical lines is needed.

Comment: Why add a third post when you can arrange for a pair of posts and the robot never to be colinear?

Comment: So I can't edit my comment after 5 minutes. The idea of arranging the posts to avoid a collinear arrangement didn't occur to me within that 5 minute time frame. All I could do was edit my answer. One way to arrange the posts might be to put the posts along the same edge of the robot grid.

Comment: As I understand the general setup, the team controlling the robot is *not* the one who sets up the posts. They are just given the coordinates (or something euivalent) of the posts and must live with it.

Comment: Well then hopefully the posts are arranged to avoid the possibility of a collinear position. Another way to code around this is to keep an internal record of position calculations. Then compute a linear approximation of the path the robot was taking for the computing the position when in a collinear configuration.

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for the replies! To clarify, the post positions are known before the robot runs. Their "absolute" positions are given to the team running the robot (the robot has knowledge of where each pipe is). These posts are positioned so that they can never be colinear with each other when viewed from any position on the board. The robot itself will determine the angles between any posts using its camera/servo. It is able to determine angles ARB, ARC, and BRC, for example.

Comment: Then my method of intersecting lines should work nicely!

Comment: No, your method does not work. The reason is that the following assumption is invalid: "Suppose you have post A at $(x_A,y_A)$ and post B at $(x_B,y_B)$ and let $θ_A$ be the angle that the robot R makes with post A..."  There is nothing in the setup that will given the robot a sense of where the x-axis or the y-axis are. Consider yourself lost on some plain on a crowded day. You may have an instrument to measure angles between known landmarks, but you do not know where the north-south or east-west directions are (which would be the equivalent of knowing the axes).

Comment: The OP clearly states that the robot can determine the angle between itself and a single post. So somehow my method can't work when it relies on precisely on what the OP says to assume?

Comment: The OP wrote that in his problem description, yes. But then he wrote just above you: "The robot itself will determine the angles between any posts using its camera/servo. It is able to determine angles ARB, ARC, and BRC, for example". If you know a bit about how those kinds of robots usually work, that is the statement that makes sense: That angle can be measured pure locally by the robot. If you want to include that the robot knows where 'north' or 'east' is, then you need to include some kind of compass in it. (To be continued in next comment)

Comment: I see that the initial problem statement is made in a way that makes your solution possible. However, all that has been clarified later by the OP (the usage of a camera, the angles it can measure) convinces me that the original statement about being able to "determine the angles between itself and any post (A, B, C, etc)" was simply misformulated.

Answer (score 0):

If the only measurement you can make is the angle form by 2 rays from the robots to 2 points, then 3 points are insufficient, but 4 is. This is due to a Mobius transformation of circle reflection $z\rightarrow 1/z$. Treat the plane as $\mathbb{C}$, with the unit circle at the origin to be the unique circle through 3 points (which exist unless 3 points are collinear, in which case line reflection show that there are 2 possible solutions). Then the circle reflection will fix all angle and the 3 points, while sending one solution to another. So with 3 points you can only pin down the possible position to 2 points. This should be enough if there are additional constraints (such as dead reckoning), but theoretically not sufficient.

So now let's say you assume there are 3 noncollinear points, and let $O$ be the center of the unique circle containing 3 points, then let $O$ be the origin and rescale your unit so that the circle is a unit circle, and assuming the robot always stay inside the circle. Let $a,b,c$ denote the position of $A,B,C$ treated as $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Let $\alpha,\beta$ be the $\cos$ of angle $ARB,BRC$.

Now calculate $d=((a+b)/2)/\overline{(a+b)/2}$. Now solve for $t$ in $\alpha((a-td)\cdot d)^{2}=(a-td)\cdot(a-td)$ which is just quadratic, and make sure $t\leq 1$. This give $td$ the point $D$ such that $ADB$ is twice $ARB$. Do the same for $BC$ and $\beta$ to get $E$. Now intersect the circle centered at $D$ which contain $B$ with the circle centered at $E$ which contains $B$. They should intersect at $B$ and another point, which is what you need (find intersection of 2 circles you can look up the formula).

Of course, there are plenty of probably faster method, but this is the straightforward geometry way.